# How to Horizontally Center Text in a JavaFX ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there any way to horizontally center the text in a `javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox`?  I am looking to center the text in the `ChoiceBox`, as well as the dropdown that opens when in the process of selecting a value.

Comment: One option is to use a ComboBox instead, and set its cellFactory and buttonCell properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the recommendation of @VGR, I changed my implementation to use a `javafx.scene.control.ComboBox`.  Then, I created a class called `CenteredListCell`:

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;

public class CenteredListCell<T> extends ListCell<T> {

    /** Default constructor */
    public CenteredListCell() {
        setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(final T item, final boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty || item == null ? null : item.toString());
    }

}
```

Next, I created the following utility method (thanks to @kleopatra for the inspiration that lead to `runWhenSkinned`):

```
private static void runWhenSkinned(final Control control, final Runnable operation) {
    final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<?> skinProperty = control.skinProperty();
    if (skinProperty.get() == null) {
        // Run after the control has been skinned
        skinProperty.addListener(observable -> Platform.runLater(operation));
    } else {
        // Run now, since the control is already skinned
        operation.run();
    }
}

public static <T> void center(final ComboBox<T> comboBox) {
    runWhenSkinned(comboBox, () -> {
        // Get the width of the combo box arrow button
        final Region arrow = (Region)comboBox.lookup(".arrow-button");
        final double arrowWidth = arrow.getWidth();

        // Create a centered button cell
        final ListCell<T> buttonCell = new CenteredListCell<T>();
        comboBox.setButtonCell(buttonCell);

        // Create an insets object with uneven horizontal padding
        final Insets oldPadding = buttonCell.getPadding();
        final Insets newPadding = new Insets(oldPadding.getTop(),
                arrowWidth, oldPadding.getBottom(), 0);

        // Replace the default cell factory
        comboBox.setCellFactory(listView -> new CenteredListCell<T>() {
            { setPadding(newPadding); }
        });
    });
}
```

The end result is a `ComboBox` with centered text in both the button cell and list-view of items.

Comment: you can register a listener to the combo's skin property and call the utility method when notified of a new skin